# How to update nested array using rethinkdb javascript driver

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I've checked other related questions, in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133460/how-to-update-embedded-document). But since that was answered it seems like rethink's handling of nested fields [has changed](http://rethinkdb.com/blog/1.8-release/).

I'm trying to modify the nested arrays 'amy' and 'joe':

```
{
    "id":  "blah" ,
    "schedules": {
        "amy": ['some', 'stuff', 'here'],
        "joe": ['more', 'stuff', 'here']
    }
}
```

I've tried all kinds of different approaches, but I can't get it to work in a single call to the database. Instead, I'm having to grab the existing array using one call:

```
r.table('whatevs').get('blah').pluck({schedules: {amy: true}})
```

this gives me something that looks like:

```
"schedules": {
    "amy": ['some', 'stuff', 'here']
}
```

so I pull out schedules.amy and modify the array then...

```
r.table('whatevs').get('blah').update({schedules: {amy: [modified_array]}})...
```

What I'd like to do is modify the arrays in place with a single query using .difference() and .append(). It seems like this is now possible, but no matter what syntax I try it gets rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update a single key that's an array, you can do so like this:

```
r.table('whateves').get('blah').update(function(row) {
  return {schedules: {amy: row('schedules')('amy').append('new_value')}};
});
```