# Filter an object in array by id in rethinkdb

Tags: database, rethinkdb, insert-update

TLDR: The largest problem I am facing is that I don't see how to filter an object inside an array by a key that is nested inside one of its objects.

Assuming a schema with this structure:

```
{
   some_field: "value",
   some_array: [
     {
        item: {
          id: "some rethinkdb key",
          name: "some object"
        },
        relevant_field: {
          id: "some rethinkdb key",
          name: "so relevant",
          properties: [
            {
              id: "target key",
              count: 2
            },
            {
              id: "some other rethinkdb key",
              count: 1
            },
          ]
        }
     },
     {
        item: ...
     }
   ]
}
```

The problem is the following: I wish to update the 'count' field inside properties for an object inside some_array with id 'target key'. The best way I have found so far is to find the position in 'some_array' of the item I wish to update, and then apply the method found in this question, provided by the accepted answer: [How to update embedded document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133460/how-to-update-embedded-document). I have successfully used that very method on other problems, but not in this one.

**EDIT**: Fixed the json structure thanks to mlucy's comment.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your example.  The objects in `some_array` appear to have two fields, both of which have `id`s, and the syntax for `properties` is incorrect (I can't figure out if it's supposed to be an array or an object).

Comment: @mlucy Thanks, it was indeed a mistake. Properties is an array of objects, and I want to update one of those objects by id.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
table.update(function(row) {
  return {some_array: row('some_array').map(function(el) {
    return {relevant_field: {properties: el('relevant_field')('properties').map(function(prop) {
      return r.branch(prop('id').eq('target key'), prop.merge({count: prop('count').add(1)}), prop);
    })}};
  })};
})
```

Comment: I have tested this code, and the count is not increased. Besides, it is not filtering at any point to update only a specific some_array object, but is instead trying to update all of them. Sorry it took me so long to respond to this answer.